# What is the name of this function in the animation in blender

Tags: animation

I'm new to blender and I have a question. In the picture I attached, there are squares that I understand help in animation, what is it called? I need to find such a pattern, but I don't know what to call this way of animation.
[image]

Comment: The "square" you show selected is a bone, which has a custom shape to give it its look. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: this is the photo from the video, I want to know how this can be done or how I can find a ready-made model with these settings?

Comment: You can custom the shape of your bones, or you can use an addon like auto-rig or rigify that will automatically create customed bones

Comment: It's a really broad question. Any rigged model at least have an armature, and might also have custom shapes if the rig is made in Blender. But custom shapes are just aesthetics, they have nothing functional, and they come in many forms and shapes, anything the rigger wanted to do. There are tools to help you rig models quickly, like Rigify mentioned above, there are tons of tutorials online about rigging in Blender in general, or with Rigify, or making custom shapes for your own rig, ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.